# Reply to messages in child processes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for an effective way to reply to a message sent to a child process. Currently, I am using the following code:

```
 const { fork } = require('child_process');
 const child = fork(path.join(__dirname, 'sub.js'));

 async function run() {
   console.log('Requesting status....');
   child.send('status');
   const status = await awaitMessage(child);
   console.log(status);
 }

 function awaitMessage(childProcess) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
     childProcess.on('message', (m) => {
       resolve(m);
     });
   });
 }
```

The problem of this code is that it creates a new event listener every single time the `awaitMessage()` function is called, which is prone to memory leaks. Is there an elegant way of receiving a reply from the child process?

Comment: why would that be prone to memory leaks? Once the instance is no more referenced (on return), it is freed.

Comment: Well I plan on this method being run multiple times/sec. Depending on how long it takes for the child process to return, there could be dozens of event listeners open at the same time.

Comment: dozens does not seem like a trouble. Eventually you want to manage them within a pool. This is how threads are managed and contained in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really "prone to memory leaks" in that a leak is something that is supposed to get freed (per the rules of the garbage collector), but isn't.  In this case, you've left a promise hooked up to an event handler that can still get called so the system simply can't know that you intend for it to be freed.

So, the system is retaining exactly what your code told it to retain.  It's the consequence of how your code works that it is retaining every promise ever created in `awaitMessage()` and also firing a bunch of extra event handlers too.  Because you keep the event listener, the garbage collector sees that the promise is still "reachable" by that listener and thus cannot and should not remove the promise even if there are no outside references to it (per the rules of the Javascript garbage collector).

If you're going to add an event listener inside a promise, then you have to remove that event listener when the promise resolves so that the promise can eventually be freed.  A promise is no magic object in Javascript, it's just a regular object so as long as you have an object that can be referenced by a live event listener, that object can't be garbage collected.

In addition, this is subject to race conditions if you ever call `awaitMessage()` twice in a row as both promises will then respond to the next message that comes.  In general, this is just not a good design approach.  If you want to wait for a message, then you have to somehow tag your messages so you know which message response is the actual one you're waiting for to avoid your race conditions and you have to remove the event listener after you get your message.

To avoid the memory build-up because of the accumulation of listeners, you can do this:

```
 function awaitMessage(childProcess) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
     function handleMsg(m) {
       childProcess.removeListener(handleMsg);
       resolve(m);
     }
     childProcess.on('message', handleMsg);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Added code example for removing listener to allow promises to be GCed.

Comment: @JohnLandon - Did this answer your question?